# Unable to install/load jupyter using anaconda

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I was unable to open my previous version of jupyter, so I deleted and uninstalled anaconda completely before re-installing it on ubuntu using:

```
bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

However, I'm unable to launch jupyter notebook using:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Error code:

> -bash: /home/melissachua/.local/bin/jupyter: /home/melissachua/anaconda3/envs/scenic_protocol/bin/python: bad
> interpreter: No such file or directory

I tried to use `pip3 install jupyter` but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

use jupyter notebook through cmd instead if there's no issue with that.
You can install through pip:

```
$pip3 install jupyter
```

Note that you have added python and pip to path.

Then you can start jupyter notebook server like:

```
$jupyter notebook
```

OR

```
$python3 -m jupyter notebook
```

Comment: I tried `pip3 install jupyter` but I'm still getting the same error `-bash: /home/melissachua/.local/bin/jupyter: /home/melissachua/anaconda3/envs/scenic_protocol/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Have you installed pip3 separatly?